# Add 7 days to existing date

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have this input with my products date posted:

```
<input type="text" id="count" hidden="true" value="{{$product->created_at}}"/>
```

I want to add 7 days to this date. This is my jQuery code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 var count = $("#count").val();

   $(".clock")
   .countdown(count, function(event) {
    $(this).text(
      event.strftime('%Hh %Mmin %Ssek')
    );
  });
 </script>
```

It shows the current date but I want to add 7 more days. Can u help me ?

Comment: Hard to help with a plugin that has no documentation link provided

Comment: @charlietfl http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/documentation.html here

Comment: Can you give an example of what the value would be of the input? Would it be "15/02/2016", or "2016-02-15" or "9:50:03.0001" or ...?

Comment: @trincot `2016-03-01 11:09:41`

Comment: plugin exposes the date object, use that to do what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `#count` contains the date you would like to work with, try the following:

```
var inputDate = new Date($('#count').val());
inputDate.setDate( inputDate.getDate() + 7 );
console.log(inputDate);
```

Comment: It works. But is there anyway to add 7 days hours to current date hours and display it without days only with hours ?

Comment: I'm unsure. You appear to be using some kind of plugin that wasn't referenced in your post or the tags. I answered the question you asked, which was how to add 7 days to a date using javascript and jquery.